# Any curve with the area under a curve $A$ between two fixed points of the $x$ axis. Find the $\min(\max(\text{slope}))$

Tags: calculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, area

I came across this problem while playing around with some physics :

Define a function which passes through $(0,0)$ and $(x,0)$ for which the area under the curve from $0$ to $x$ is some constant $A$, such that $|m|$ (the slope of the graph) is the least possible.

Given $x > 0$ and $A$, minimise $\max_{\xi \in [0, x]} \lvert f'(\xi) \rvert$ for differentiable functions $f \colon [0, x] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\int_0^x f(\xi) \, d\xi = A$.

For example :

Let the area under the graph from $0$ to $1$ is $1$, $|m| > M$ find $M$. I don't really have an approach, but I made a graph using straight lines with slopes $m1$ and $m2$. This give a triangle with height $2$, and we can easily see that the minimum slope would be $4$. How would this change if one sketches any graph without the compulsion of it being a first-degree polynomial function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Given $x > 0$ and $A$, are you trying to maximize $\min_{\xi \in [0, x]} \lvert f'(\xi) \rvert$ for differentiable functions $f \colon [0, x] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\int_0^x f(\xi) \, d\xi = A$?

Comment: what do you mean when you say " |m|
 (the slope of the graph) is the least possible." A graphical representation hasn't **a fixed slope** (unless it is $y=ax+b$ as you have considerd it), it has a **mean slope**

Comment: @L.F. edited the question to increase the clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rename the quantity $x$ to $a$ and assume without loss of generality that $A \ge 0$.  (The same reasoning with $A$ replaced by $-A$ applies when $A < 0$.)

We have a differentiable function $f \colon [0, a] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = f(a) = 0$ and
$$ \int_0^a f(y)\,dy = A > 0. $$
Let
$$
m = \max_{x \in [0, a/2]} \lvert f'(x) \rvert
\quad \text{and} \quad
n = \max_{x \in [a/2, a]} \lvert f'(x) \rvert.
$$
Using the fundamental theorem of calculus,
we split $A = A_1 + A_2$ where
$$
A_1 = \int_0^{a/2} f(y)\,dy
= \int_0^{a/2} \int_0^y f'(x) \, dx \, dy
\le \int_0^{a/2} \int_0^y m \, dx \, dy
= \frac{1}{8} m a^2
$$
and
$$
A_2 = \int_{a/2}^a f(y)\,dy
= \int_{a/2}^a \biggl( -\int_y^a f'(x) \, dx \biggr) \, dy
\le \int_{a/2}^a \int_y^a n \, dx \, dy
= \frac{1}{8} n a^2.
$$
Hence,
$$
\max\{m, n\} \ge \frac{m + n}{2}
\ge \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{A}{\frac{1}{8} a^2}
= \frac{4A}{a^2},
$$
where equality holds if and only if
$m = n = f'(x_1) = - f'(x_2)$
for almost all $x_1 \in [0, a/2]$ and $x_2 \in [a/2, a]$,
which happens precisely when the graph of $f$ is the polygonal chain
$$ (0, 0) - \biggl(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{2A}{a}\biggr) - (a, 0) $$
by [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).
This optimal case is not admissible since $f$ would not be differentiable at $\frac{a}{2}$, but it can be approximated to arbitrary precision by slightly raising the graph and rounding the corner.  Therefore, we conclude that
$$
\inf_{f} \max_{x \in [0, a]} \lvert f'(x) \rvert
= \frac{4 \lvert A \rvert}{a^2}.
$$